# ElixirからErlangのrecordを扱う方法

Tags: erlang, elixir

Erlangのrecordを使うときは、Record.extractを使えばよいことを知りましたが、結構長くなります。

```
iex(1)> require Record
nil

iex(2)> r = Record.extract(:sctp_initmsg, from_lib: "kernel/include/inet_sctp.hrl")
[num_ostreams: :undefined, max_instreams: :undefined, max_attempts: :undefined,
max_init_timeo: :undefined]
```

毎回これを書く以外に、方法はあるでしょうか？
includeのような一回書けば済むものがあるとよいのですが。

Answer (score 2):

自己レスですが、別のことを調べているときに偶然、正しい(?)使用例を見つけました。  
(出典: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345939/elixir-and-erlang-records-pattern-matching)

```
defrecord :xmlText, Record.extract(:xmlText, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl")
```

レコードを使いたいときに毎回Record.extract/2を使うのではなくて、defrecordに食わせるんですね。